# VB Equivalent of "To" in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, vb6, vb6-migration

I know that in the context of loops the equivalent of `To` in `i = long1 To long2` in VB is `(i = long1; i < long2; ++i)` in C#, but I am trying to find a an equivalent of it in the context of `ReDim/System.Array.Resize()`:

**VB6**:

`ReDim indexCorr(LBound(fDefMatchs) to UBound(fDefMatchs)`

**C#**:

`System.Array.Resize(indexCorr, ***?)`

Does anyone else know how to resize an array in C# using a range of numbers like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
System.Array.Resize(ref indexCorr, fDefMatchs.Length);
```

However, in .NET you cannot set the lower bound of an array. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx):

> Arrays are zero indexed: an array with n elements is indexed from 0 to n-1.